# Where condition exists in top(1) row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I transform my query for better performance?

```
select *
from inventorytranstemp
where tablename = (
  select top(1) tableName
  from inventorytranstemp where printed = 1
)
```

The condition exists inside the same table with select query. How can I transform my query to seems more easy, and using less select statements?

Comment: Whats wrong with the performance? Nothing wrong with that query. One thing with SQL Server - don't try and solve a problem where there is no problem.

Comment: Ok. If this query seems ok. Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: You could try `EXISTS` instead of a scalar subquery. With a compound index on tablename and printed, I would expect optimal performance. Your existing query might perform equally well; compare the execution plans to verify.